# How to get ActorRefs of all children of a RouterPool in Akka

Tags: scala, akka, akka-supervision

I create a RouterPool of an actor like this:

```
val myActorPool = Akka.system.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[MyActor]), "myActor")
```

now i would like to access the ActorRef objects of the 5 children that are managed by this router. Is there some method call to retrieve that for all children? Or do i have to declare them explicitly and then pass them to the router?

Comment: If you want control over the children you might consider a round robin group instead of a pool.

Comment: Ok so i guess this means that there is now easy method call to get the actorRefs from a pool and i have to declare them explicitly and add them to the group.

Comment: Yes.  The pooled actors are meant to be out of your control.  If you need control over them use a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sending `akka.routing.GetRoutees` to a router actor will make it send back its currently used routees in a `akka.routing.Routees` message

from: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.11/scala/routing.html#Managagement_Messages

Comment: Ok this doesn't return actual ActorRef objects but Routee seems to be sufficient for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but here's how I did it, provided you're using `Routee`s that are `ActorRefRoutee`:

```
val actor: Option[ActorRefRoutee] = myActorPool.logic.select("Hello", routees /*Should be able to generate these from router*/) match { 
 case actorRefRoutee: ActorRefRoutee => 
   Some(actorRefRoutee) 
 case _ => 
   None
}
```

then you can get the actor reference by calling:

```
actor.ref
```

Answer (score 0):

A long time has passed and I had the same question about Akka.Net and did not find a working answer. Discovering type of the returned objects in the debugger helped me:

```
_router.Tell(new GetRoutees());
...
// router callback
var routees = message as Routees;
if (routees != null)
{
    IEnumerable<IActorRef> routeeRefs = routees.Members.Select(r => ((ActorRefRoutee) r).Actor);
    ...
}
```